# Which Twitter Bootstrap for MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, nuget

I wanna add Twitter Bootstrap to my MVC4 application however looking at the nuget packages there are so many different packages to choose from.
Which should I choose?

Comment: The one you want. None of them is from Microsoft, it's up-to-you. Look at their documentation and check if they answer to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official Twitter Bootstrap nuget package. They are all community maintained, so they can stop being updated at any point. So you'll probably have to skim through them and find one that you're comfortable with.

Microsoft is including Bootstrap as apart of MVC5, but I don't think it's apart of a Nuget package they are releasing (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I would just include the Bootstrap files from a CDN. I don't see, why you need NuGet here for some simple task to do that can be done with the help of CDN links.